# How can i sort two integer arrays parallel with quick sort in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, quicksort

I want to sort two arrays simultaneously. I am beginner in Parallelizing in c# and i want to know how i should do it, by Multithreading or something like that...

a1 and a2 are integer
quick_sort(a1,0,100);

quick_sort(a2,0,100);

how can i start these function at same time? please write the code for me

Comment: are you familiar with `Google` what if you were to type in the search, how to execute multiple methods at the same time.. ? are you familiar with `Task.Run()` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort both of these "simultaneously".

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => quick_sort(a1,0,100));
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => quick_sort(a2,0,100));
```